# Actual NAA in a wrong language considered as an answer for having relevant information?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is the answer I'm taking about: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202062/205764

The initial revision reads

> Mim ajudem, com essa mensagem q esta aparecendo no meu lenovo z5the bootloader is unlocked and software integrity cannot be guaranteed. any data stored on the device may be available to attacker, do not store any sensitive data on device

I recognized Portuguese and knew that it translated to

> Please help me with this message that's appearing on my Lenovo Z5

and flagged it as NAA after leaving a comment telling the author that they used a wrong language, as well as that the answer form was not for questions.

Izzy saw the answer and my comment, applied machine translation to the Portuguese part, got this result and declined my flag:

> I help, with this message that is appearing in my Lenovo Z5

My reason for the answer being an NAA is rather obvious: It said "please help me" with a common bootloader warning, while Izzy claimed that

> poetic license. Put this way, it's a valid answer, isn't it? "How is this a security thread?" › "any data stored on the device may be available to attacker" :)

Per my understanding, Izzy thought it was a valid answer because the BL warning contained information that could serve as an answer alone, and it could remain a valid answer with the wrong-language part translated (wrongly).

And now I disagree: While the BL message could provide some directive to an answer, it did appear in a wrong manner (coming as the error message after "please help me"). Therefore, it should not be considered as an answer, IMO. Think if the post came in English starting with "please help me" instead of an unrecognized language "mim ajudem", most people would have taken it correctly as an NAA.

Comment: Somehow reminds me of https://xkcd.com/810/ (https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/constructive.png) – giving the right answer with a wrong intention still results in a correct and useful answer. And sorry for my "poetic license", forgot the smiley there – it was indeed the "machine translation" leading me to assume an answer attempt. Question still remains: should we delete valid answers if given for the wrong reason? And am I wrong this is a valid answer?

Comment: @Izzy Poking again, do you think the result or consensus is clear now? (I voted up both answers).

Comment: OK, I bow to the community. "Answer" is deleted now.

Answer (score 7):

I'm in agreement with you. It is indeed a [general bootloader warning](https://source.android.com/security/images/boot_orange.png). What's more? Yes, Google Translator, Bing Translator, and a voluntary translation from a trusted user on Portuguese Stack Exchange [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46925685#46925685)  give us the same result for the first sentence of the post, which translated to what you thought as *"Help me, with this message that is appearing on my lenovo z5the bootloader is (...)"*

What really follows after that sentence is not important here. I get it that we do have a policy of appreciating partial answer, but the beginning of the post already made the intention clear that it was not to serve as a partial answer. ***It was not even intended to be an answer by the user*** when the context is applied, which we must.

Even for the sake of this post we apply an exception and ignore the context, the rest of the sentence (warning that is) does not form an answer, simply because the questioner specifically mentioned in the question these two constraints:

> (I am not talking of risks of unlocked boot loader. I understand that)....
>
> I am looking for realistic threat assessment

The bootloader warning is nothing but a general and vague message (it is not even close to a realistic threat assessment which the question specifically demanded)  indicating the risks of an unlocked bootloader. Since questioner already knows it and *indirectly* asked not to repeat it to them, the warning, thus, does not qualify as an answer to the concerned question.

I, hence, as a fellow user, agree with your judgment.

Comment: P.S. When I used Google Translate it gave me the same wrong result as Izzy's, verbatim. However I knew a bit about Portuguese and rightfully decided that the result was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr: NAA, it's asking for help.

---

Your translation is correct, Izzy's is not.

The language is not grammatically correct, but it asks:

> Help me, with this message that is appearingon my lenovo z5the bootloader is (...)

It is not offering help or suggesting solutions; it's NAA.

Comment: Of course, if it helps accidentally, you can rework it so it becomes an answer... :) Greetings from the [portuguese.se] community! <3

Comment: Obrigado para o seu interesse! Can you point out how *the language is not grammatically correct*? Like a corrected version of that sentence? I came up with ***Me** ajudem, com essa mensagem **que está** aparecendo no meu lenovo z5*.

Comment: @iBug "Obrigado por"; por + o = pelo; and so: "Obrigado pelo seu interesse!" Thank you for wanting to know. :)

Comment: @iBug The grammatical mistake is just using the pronoun "mim" instead of the reflex pronoun "me". I can't explain very well the difference, but "mim" would be for indicating an indirect object where the "ajudar" verb is reflexive, and calls for the use of a "me". The "me" can be for direct or indirect objects. Abbreviating "que" to "q" and skipping accents is common in SMS and other short-writing systems, and quickly understood.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion is perfect. "Me ajudem com essa mensagem que está aparecendo no meu Lenovo Z5". That's pt-BR, in pt-PT you could write "Ajudem-me com esta mensagem que me está a aparecer no meu Lenovo Z5". :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!