# What's our stance for short and/or partial answers?

Tags: discussion, scope

We frequently got one-liners from new users like this:

> There is an option in settings to turn off Wifi scanning which will help reduce the wifi battery usage.

To me, this would be a borderline NAA as it doesn't point out where exactly the Settings option is, but it does serve as a partial answer because it gives a direction to a potential solution to the problem.

Per my experience on Stack Overflow, these one-liners are usually voted down and eventually deleted, and I've been flagging them on SO.

However, I know that we're different from SO and sometimes a single sentence can help a lot. For example, you probably don't need to explain much when you've already pointed out where the Settings item is. Some time ago an NAA was even considered as a partial answer for containing some pieces of information, which [led to a discussion](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436) about itself.

So here comes the question: What's our stance for these one-liners and partial answers?

Comment: I often convert them to comments (as they hold useful/helpful information without being real answers), and leave a comment on the (then deleted) answer explaining the background and encouraging to write up a new, complete answer. Or (when flagged, so I have a reminder) first leave the comment asking to update the answer – and convert it to a comment if there wasn't a reaction within reasonable time. Basically what I said in my answer to the linked question. Also keep in mind that sometimes, one line is all there is to say – so short doesn't necessarily mean NAA or VLQ :)